# js Бесконечно повторяющаяся функция

Tags: javascript, функции, slider

Делаю слайдер на js. Он проигрывается только 1 раз при загрузке страницы. Подскажите, что надо дописать или исправить в коде, чтобы он работал постоянно.

```js
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides .pic_1 ');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(NextSlide, 1000);
var t;
var title_forest = document.getElementById("title_forest");


function PauseSlide(){
    if(slideInterval){
     clearInterval(slideInterval);
     slideInterval = null;
  

    }
 
 
}
function WorkSlide(){
  if(!slideInterval){
  slideInterval =  setInterval(NextSlide, 1000);
 }

   
}

function Click(){

 }
 
function OnMouse(){
 PauseSlide();
    var cart = document.getElementById("cart");
    cart.style.display = "block";
    var img_1 = document.getElementById("img_1");
    if(img_1.src == "images/forest.jpg")
    {
      title_forest.style.display="block";

    }
    //var cart0 =document.getElementById("cart0");
 // cart0.style.display = "block";
 // var cart1 =document.getElementById("cart1");
 // cart1.style.display = "block";
 // var cart2 =document.getElementById("cart2");
 // cart2.style.display = "block";



} 
function LeaveMouse(){
 WorkSlide();
  var cart = document.getElementById("cart");
    cart.style.display = "none";

    //var cart0 =document.getElementById("cart0");
 // cart0.style.display = "none";
 // var cart1 =document.getElementById("cart1");
 // cart1.style.display = "none";
 // var cart2 =document.getElementById("cart2");
 // cart2.style.display = "none";
}
var i=0;
var j = 0;



function NextSlide(){
 // slides[currentSlide].className = 'li_slide';
 // currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
 // slides[currentSlide].className = 'li_slide showing';
    var imgMas =[
  "images/forest.jpg",
  "images/desert.jpg",
  "images/sea.jpg"
  
 ];
 
   if(i < imgMas.length ){
     img_1.src = imgMas[i];
 }
  i++;  
    }
this.setInterval(NextSlide, 1000);
function up() {
  var top = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  if(top > 0) {
    window.scrollBy(0,-60);
    t = setTimeout('up()',60);
  } else clearTimeout(t);
  return false;
}
```

```css
body{
    background:#CDB5CD;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 2500px;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

.slides{
    width: 890px;
    height:500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.cartain{
    width: 889px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.4);
    display: none;
    position: relative;
   }
   .pic_1{
    position: absolute;
   }
   .name_forest, .name_sea, .name_desert{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffff;
    font-weight: initial;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:50%;
    margin: -60px;
   }
   .name_sea{
    padding-left:32px;
   }
   

   button{
    width: 120px;
    height:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    top:400px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    outline: none;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    background: transparent;
    border:1px solid #1C1C1C;
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.6);
   }
   button:active{
    color: #ffff;
     border:1px solid #ffff;
   }

/*.li_slide{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
.li_slide:nth-of-type(1){
    width: 889px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../images/forest.jpg);
}
.li_slide:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 889px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../images/sea.jpg);
}
.li_slide:nth-of-type(3){
    width: 889px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../images/desert.jpg);
}*/
.text{
    max-width: 870px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    color: #ffff;
    position: relative;
}
 .name_forest{
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    display: none;
}
.pic_forest{
    width: 360px;
    height:160px;
    margin-top: 84px;
   /* border-radius: 10px;*/
}
.text div{
    width: 500px;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    left:378px;
    bottom: 180px;
}
.p2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 198px;
    top:460px;
}
.arrow_up{
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    border:8px solid black;
    border-radius: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    top:540px;
    
}
ш

.arrow_up:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.4);
}
.arrow_up:active{
     background: rgba(156, 156, 156, 1);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slides" onmouseenter="OnMouse()" onmouseleave="LeaveMouse()">
   <img id="img_1" class="pic_1" src="images/forest.jpg">
   <div class="cartain" id="cart">
    <h1 id="title_forest" class="name_forest">Forest</h1>
    <button>More</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <ul class="slides">
   <li  class="li_slide showing" onmouseenter="OnMouse()" onmouseleave="LeaveMouse()">
    <div class="cartain" id="cart0">
     <h1 class="name_forest">Forest</h1>
     <button onclick="Click()">More</button>
    </div>
   </li>
      <li  class="li_slide" onmouseenter="OnMouse()" onmouseleave="LeaveMouse()">
       <div class="cartain" id="cart1">
        <h1 class="name_sea">Sea</h1>
        <button>More</button>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="li_slide" onmouseenter="OnMouse()" onmouseleave="LeaveMouse()">
       <div class="cartain" id="cart2">
        <h1 class="name_desert">Desert</h1>
        <button>More</button>
       </div>
      </li>
  </ul> -->
  <div  class="text" class="text_forest">
         <h1>Evergreen forest</h1>
         <img class="pic_forest" src="images/foto_forest.jpg" alt="foto_forest">
         <div>
             <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu hendrerit tellus. Sed non purus nibh. Pellentesque mattis risus orci, at luctus libero venenatis vitae. Suspendisse in faucibus est, in bibendum mauris. Vivamus vitae imperdiet velit, vitae iaculis odio. Sed mauris metus, mollis ut quam ac, sodales tincidunt turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                </p>     
         </div>
          <p class="p2">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu hendrerit tellus. Sed non purus nibh. Pellentesque mattis risus orci, at luctus libero venenatis vitae. Suspendisse in faucibus est, in bibendum mauris. Vivamus vitae imperdiet velit, vitae iaculis odio. Sed mauris metus, mollis ut quam ac, sodales tincidunt turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                    Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                   
                </p>       
  </div>
  <div  class="text" class="text_sea">
   <h1>Black sea</h1>
         <img class="pic_forest" src="images/foto_sea.jpg" alt="foto_sea">
         <div>
             <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu hendrerit tellus. Sed non purus nibh. Pellentesque mattis risus orci, at luctus libero venenatis vitae. Suspendisse in faucibus est, in bibendum mauris. Vivamus vitae imperdiet velit, vitae iaculis odio. Sed mauris metus, mollis ut quam ac, sodales tincidunt turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
             </p>
      </div>
         <p class="p2">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu hendrerit tellus. Sed non purus nibh. Pellentesque mattis risus orci, at luctus libero venenatis vitae. Suspendisse in faucibus est, in bibendum mauris. Vivamus vitae imperdiet velit, vitae iaculis odio. Sed mauris metus, mollis ut quam ac, sodales tincidunt turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                    Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                   
                </p> 
        </div>

  <div  class="text" class="text_desert" >
         <h1>Sahara desert</h1>
         <img class="pic_forest" src="images/foto_desert.jpg" alt="foto_desert">
         <div>
             <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu hendrerit tellus. Sed non purus nibh. Pellentesque mattis risus orci, at luctus libero venenatis vitae. Suspendisse in faucibus est, in bibendum mauris. Vivamus vitae imperdiet velit, vitae iaculis odio. Sed mauris metus, mollis ut quam ac, sodales tincidunt turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
             </p>
         </div>
         <p class="p2">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu hendrerit tellus. Sed non purus nibh. Pellentesque mattis risus orci, at luctus libero venenatis vitae. Suspendisse in faucibus est, in bibendum mauris. Vivamus vitae imperdiet velit, vitae iaculis odio. Sed mauris metus, mollis ut quam ac, sodales tincidunt turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                    Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus bibendum, nisl a venenatis molestie, sem ipsum tristique purus, sit amet commodo nisl augue vel lorem.
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. Quisque vitae neque at elit fringilla interdum ut ac felis. Suspendisse in velit massa. 
                    Maecenas orci metus, iaculis nec gravida eget, rutrum semper nulla. 
                </p> 
  </div>
      
 </div> 
        <div class="arrow_up" onclick="return up()">
       <a href="#"><img src="images/arrow_up.png" alt="arrow_up"></a>
  </div>
</body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Необходим **минимальный** пример, а глядя на эту простыню, мне лень даже помочь, ибо надо разбирать что к чему, хотя ответ может быть одним предложением.

Comment: вот же - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839978/js-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-onmouseenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам на днях делал слайдер. С такой же проблемой столкнулся по моему. Короче проблема там была в том что for луп и setinterval функция ... крч вот так я сделал. посмотри может поможет :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="content" >
    <img style="max-width: 700px" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/schan/schan1610/schan161000193/65877041-girl-ass-outdoors.jpg" alt="" id="sausage">
</div>


    <script>

    var myArray = ['https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/82/40/3e8240674dcd163e242c82f89aeaa17c.jpg',
                    'https://nextshark-vxdsockgvw3ki.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/2-13.jpg',
                    'https://previews.123rf.com/images/schan/schan1610/schan161000193/65877041-girl-ass-outdoors.jpg'
                    ];

var words = ['Hello', ', ', 'I ', 'am ', 'in ', 'a ', 'loop', '...'];

// (1) define the variable for the array index
var i = 0;

// (2) define the delayed loop function
function delayedLoop()
{
// (3) do action
 document.querySelector('#sausage').src = myArray[i];

// (4) if the end of the array has been reached, stop
if(++i == myArray.length)
{
i = 0;
}

// (5) recursively call the delayed loop function with a delay
window.setTimeout(delayedLoop, 1000);
}
delayedLoop(); // (6) start the loop


// function cycle(index) {
//     setTimeout(function() {
//         document.querySelector('#sausage').src = myArray[index];

//         index++; // Increment the index

//         if (index >= myArray.length) {
//             index = 0; // Set it back to `0` when it reaches `3`
//         }

//         cycle(index); // recursively call `cycle()`

//         //cycle(++index % 3);
//     }, 1000);
// }

// cycle(0);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[код](https://jsfiddle.net/80dj1qt9)